# What is the relationship between open and connected sets and statistical independence?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\vol}{\operatorname{vol}}$Suppose that $U \sim \operatorname{Unif}(C)$, $0 < \vol(C) < \infty$ with $U = (X, Y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^p = \mathbb{R}^r \times \mathbb{R}^s $.

Verify that if $C$ is open and connected then $X\mathrel{\perp\!\!\!\perp}Y \iff C = A \times B$

I've come up with a proof but as far as I can tell it doesn't matter if the sets are open and connected which makes me suspicious. Where is that necessary?

$\Rightarrow$

$$X\mathrel{\perp\!\!\!\perp}Y \Rightarrow P(X \in E_1, Y \in E_2) = P(X \in E_1)P(Y \in E_2)$$

Since $U = (X, Y)$

$$P(X \in E_1, Y \in E_2) = P(U \in E_1 \times E_2)=P(X \in E_1)P(Y \in E_2)$$

where for clarity I assumed $E_1 \times E_2 \subset C$, but this could be relaxed. Then, because $U$ has a uniform distribution on $C$,

$$P(U \in E_1 \times E_2)=\frac{\vol(E_1 \times E_2)}{\vol(C)} = \frac{\vol(E_1)}{\vol(A)}\frac{\vol(E_2)}{\vol(B)}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are the sets where $X$ and $Y$ are defined, respectively.

Now turning this into densities we have that

$$\frac{I(E_1 \times E_2)}{\vol(C)} = \frac{I(E_1)}{\vol(A)}\frac{I(E_2)}{\vol(B)}$$
$$\frac{I(E_1)I(E_2)}{\vol(C)} = \frac{I(E_1)}{\vol(A)}\frac{I(E_2)}{\vol(B)}$$

where $I$ is the indicator function. Since the numerators are the same this means that $\vol(C) = \vol(A)\vol(B)$. Applying Fubini's theorem,

$$\int_Cdx = \int_Adx \int_Bdy = \int_{A \times B}d(x, y)$$

and so the set $C$ is $A \times B$.

$\Leftarrow$

Since $C = A \times B$,

$$\frac{I(E_1 \times E_2)}{\vol(C)} = \frac{I(E_1)I(E_2)}{\vol(A)\vol(B)} $$

hence $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Might it be that you proved that the volume of the symmetric difference between $C$ and $A\times B$ is $0,$ and that you need some well-behavedness of these sets to go from there to the conclusion that the symmetric difference is empty? $\qquad$